# How to form an equation to solve for a variable for if-then-else equation

Tags: notation, computer-science

I have a formula which looks like this, it has 4 different parameters **`t,b,c,d`**. It calculates, **`p`** for a given `t,b,c,d`. Apologies in advance, I don't know how to enter the mathematical equations here.

[image: Equation]

```
//javascript equivalent of the eqaution
function calculateP(t, b, c, d) {
    return (2 * t / d < 1) ? (c / 2) * (2 * t / d) * (2 * t / d) + b : (-c / 2) * ((2 * t / d - 1) * (2 * t / d - 1 - 2) - 1) + b;
};
```

For example,

**`if t =0.45; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** the above results in **`110.75`**.

**`if t =0.3; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** the above results in **`77`**.

**`if t =0.95; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** the above results in **`199.25`**.

My question is how can I reverse this equation, to formulate an equation that would calculate the value of **`t`** for a given **`p,b,c,d`**?

For example, what would be the equation for t if I have

**`if p=110.75; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** that would result in **`t =0.45`**.

**`if p =77; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** that would result in **`t =0.3`**.

**`if p=199.25; b = 50; c = 150; d =1;`** that would result in **`t =0.95`**.

Comment: Your JavaScript equivalent has an extra `-1` near the end of the formula? Both of your examples satisfy $\frac{2t}{d}<1$, so I can't tell which one is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for that. The javascript is correct. The picture of the mathematical equation notation should match the javascript now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \frac{2t}{d}$. Set an intermediate value $y$ that will be the main step for inversion:

$$\begin{align*}
y &= \begin{cases}
x^2,&x < 1\\
-[(x-1)(x-3)-1], &x\ge 1
\end{cases}\\
p &= \frac c2\cdot y+b
\end{align*}$$

Given $p,b,c,d$, the first and the last steps are easier to invert:

$$\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{2(p-b)}c\\
t &= \frac{xd}2
\end{align*}$$

For the middle step, to find $x$ given $y$,

$$\begin{align*}
y &= \begin{cases}
x^2,&x < 1\\
1-(x-1)(x-3), &x\ge 1
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
x^2,&x < 1\\
-x^2+4x-2, &x\ge 1
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
x^2,&x < 1\\
2-(x-2)^2, &x\ge 1
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}$$

Depending on the values of $y$, there may be $1$ to $3$ real roots of $x$:

$$x = \begin{cases}2+\sqrt{2-y},&y< 0\\
\pm\sqrt y \text{ or } 2+\sqrt{2-y},&0\le y < 1\\
-\sqrt y \text{ or } 2\pm\sqrt{2-y},&1\le y \le 2\\
-\sqrt y, &y>2
\end{cases}$$

---

For your examples of $b=50, c=150, d=1$, the above may give extra real roots:

- If $p=110.75$, then $y=0.81$, and $x=\pm 0.9 \text{ or }2+\sqrt{1.19}$.
- If $p=77$, then $y=0.36$, and $x=\pm0.6 \text{ or }2+\sqrt{1.64}$.
- If $p=199.25$, then $y=1.99$, and $x = -\sqrt{1.99} \text{ or } 2\pm 0.1$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check this out with my production element. I usually use [SymbolLab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/solve-for-equation-calculator/solve%20for%20t%2C%202t-s%3Dp?or=ex) to generate equation for `solve for t` which I can easily convert into a code. However, in this case, I could not use it as I did not how to enter if then else in SymbolLab. I do have few more with if then else that needs conversion. Is there a tool I can use for solve for t.